# error connecting to database using aiosqlite python libraries

Tags: python, sqlite, asynchronous

There is documentation for the library. I am using the code from there:

https://aiosqlite.omnilib.dev/en/latest/?badge=latest

```
import aiosqlite

db = await aiosqlite.connect("db.db")
cursor = await db.execute('SELECT * FROM Users')
row = await cursor.fetchone()
rows = await cursor.fetchall()
await cursor.close()
await db.close()
```

**Gives an error message**

```
  File "database.py", line 3
    db = await aiosqlite.connect("db.db")
         ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function
```

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your `await` statements inside a coroutine:

```
import aiosqlite

async def aio_db_stuff():
   db = await aiosqlite.connect("db.db")
   cursor = await db.execute('SELECT * FROM Users')
   row = await cursor.fetchone()
   rows = await cursor.fetchall()
   await cursor.close()
   await db.close()
```

To run the coroutine, import the `asyncio` module from the standard library and pass `aio_db_stuff` to it:

```
import asyncio
asyncio.run(aio_db_stuff())
```